# Change the bold font into regular font opencv

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract

How can i make the bold text inside an image to appear regular using opencv library to obtain better accuracy for Tesseract text extraction library? I tried morphology Dilate to make it appear less thick but ends up getting losing accent mark(my language is Vietnamese) like the image below:

[image: Input]

I want something similiar to this:

[image: Output]

Comment: do you know any cv library or algorithm that can fix it ?

Comment: apologies please, misread your post.

Comment: Dilate  will also decrease the accuracy of the OCR since it change the edges shape

Comment: So what do i have to do?